Starting a program from the CLI with some File Properties Options activated
Start a program from the CLI with some File Properties Options activated
I want to start from the CLI automatically a graphical application with a File properties flag setted.
High DPI scalling overide , Scalling peformed by Application
The program start perfectly doing .\vcxsrv.exe :0 -multiwindow
I have checked  a solution and it looks like there is a way by doing a .\vcxsrv.exe.manifest
I have done such including the following content
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <application>
        <windowsSettings>
            <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
            <dpiAwareV2 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true/pm</dpiAwareV2>
        </windowsSettings>
    </application>

Nothing is happening.
Anyone knows how to tackle this issue. I have seen some solutions but tweaking some registry keys , which I wanted to avoid. Although if it is the only solution please let me know.
